Random failure of playwright test due to timeout, if execution is done via bitbucket pipeline
Error-screenshotI am running my playwright test using docker image image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.49.0-noble
on edge,chrome,safari & firefox browsers using bitbucket pipeline.
Some tests are randomly failing due to timeout sometimes on fiefox or chrome even though sufficient wait is available.Once n several attempt, all tests are green as well. Locally also it works fine.
Below is the code for waituntil function.
async waitUntil(func, timeout = 1000, pollingRate = 100) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(interval);
                reject(new Error('WaitUntil timed out'));
            }, timeout);
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (!func())
                    return;

                clearTimeout(timer);
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve();
            }, pollingRate);
        });
    }

Can anyone suggest something how the test can be stabilized in this case?
I tried disabling parallel execution -> no success
Already introduced sufficient wait but still no help.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Don't use waits at all. But beyond that, please share a [mcve] -- I'm not sure what to make of this chunk of code taken out of context. Almost certainly, use an auto-waiting locator, waitForFunction or expect().toPass() instead of a hand-rolled poll. Thanks.

One potential reason could be somewhere in your tests await keyword might be missing ?
Also, what's the actionTimeout value in your playwright config?

Maybe it's just better to wrap it expect.poll?
await expect.poll(async () => {
  const response = await page.request.get('https://api.example.com');
  return response.status();
}, {
  // Custom expect message for reporting, optional.
  message: 'make sure API eventually succeeds',
  // Poll for 10 seconds; defaults to 5 seconds. Pass 0 to disable timeout.
  timeout: 10000,
}).toBe(200);

Also, it's unclear what function you're trying to resolve, so there's no way to debug it here.

This is helpful , thanks!
